# show past and future date asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, c#-4.0

I need to show dates as below.
(The dates are in spanish)

> Lunes 16 de marzo | Martes 17 de marzo | Miércoles 18 de marzo | Jueves 19 de marzo | Viernes 20 de marzo 20

I need to display 5 dates, and third date in the group must be today.

Anyone know how to start?

Comment: Look at `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.AddDays()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, comments inline:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // slecting locale
        var ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

        // use a StringBuilder for storing the processed text
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // use an Enumerable
        Enumerable.Range(-2, 5)
            // get date range
            .Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(i))
            // get long dates in es-ES and remove ","
            .Select(i => i.ToString("D", ci).Replace(",", ""))
            .ToList().ForEach(s =>
            {
                // capitalize first letter
                sBuilder.Append(char.ToUpper(s[0]));
                // remove the year part
                sBuilder.Append(s.Substring(1, s.LastIndexOf(' ') - 3));
                // add delimiter
                sBuilder.Append("| ");
            });
        // adjust length for removing the final delimiter
        sBuilder.Length = sBuilder.Length - 2;

        Console.WriteLine(sBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this :

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
```

and then you just format your output the way you need.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use the DateTime object to get the current DateTime and then use DateTime's methods to get the previous 2 and next 2.  DateTime's AddDay (or AddMinute, Second, etc...) can take a negative number.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime prevOne = myDate.AddDays(-1);
DateTime prevTwo = myDate.AddDays(-2);
DateTime nextOne = myDate.AddDays(1);
DateTime nextTwo = myDate.AddDays(2);
```

Display them in the order prevTwo, prevOne, myDate, nextOne, nextTwo.  I'm assuming that your regional settings are taking care of the translation to Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

I would it do somewhere along those lines:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
//Format your date 'de' to get the literal string into the date
var datestring = "{0:dddd dd 'de' MMMM}";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//iterate
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
   //build the string
    sb.Append(String.Format(datestring + " | ", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2+x)));
}
sb.ToString().Dump();
```

Output:

> martes 17 de marzo | miércoles 18 de marzo | jueves 19 de marzo |
>   viernes 20 de marzo | sábado 21 de marzo

edit: a nicer way, which gets rid of the trailing "|" and seperates the data aggregation from the presentation:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

var dateFormat = "dddd dd 'de' MMMM";
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    //push dates into our List
    dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2+x));
}
//build the output string and format our dates
String.Join(" | ", dates.Select (d => d.ToString(dateFormat))).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Declare a string
For (var i=0; i<5;i++)
{      
  string += " (today -2 +i) formatted in any way you want "
}
Display the string
```